# chromium build failure on ubuntu-20.04

Tags: typescript, chromium, ubuntu-20.04

I wanted to try building Chromium, so I followed [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/linux/build_instructions.md#Setting-up-the-build). but I got an error while building.

I just get the code using fetch command with --no-history. of course, I think that the packages with dependencies were properly installed using scripts according to the documentation.
I'm just following the document guide, so I don't know where to start to fix this. I am a chromium newbie.

Here is an error message. How can I solve this?

```bash
$ gn gen out/Default
$ autoninja -C out/Default chrome
ninja: Entering directory `out/Default'
[218/26862] ACTION //chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list:build_ts(//build/toolchain/linux:clang_x64)
FAILED: gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/tsconfig_build_ts.json gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/build_ts.manifest gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/tsc/app.js gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/tsc/app.d.ts gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/tsc/reading_list_item.js gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/tsc/reading_list_item.d.ts gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/tsc/reading_list_api_proxy.js gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/tsc/reading_list_api_proxy.d.ts gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/tsc/app.html.js gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/tsc/app.html.d.ts gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/tsc/reading_list_item.html.js gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/tsc/reading_list_item.html.d.ts gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/tsc/icons.html.js gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/tsc/icons.html.d.ts gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/tsc/reading_list.mojom-webui.js gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/tsc/reading_list.mojom-webui.d.ts 
python3 ../../tools/typescript/ts_library.py --root_dir gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/preprocessed --gen_dir gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list --out_dir gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/tsc --output_suffix build_ts --in_files app.ts reading_list_item.ts reading_list_api_proxy.ts app.html.ts reading_list_item.html.ts icons.html.ts reading_list.mojom-webui.js --definitions ../../../../../../../../tools/typescript/definitions/metrics_private.d.ts --deps ../../../../../third_party/polymer/v3_0/tsconfig_library.json ../../../../../ui/webui/resources/tsconfig_library.json ../../../../../ui/webui/resources/mojo/tsconfig_library.json --tsconfig_base ../../../../../../../../chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/tsconfig_base.json --composite --path_mappings chrome://resources/cr_components/managed_footnote/managed_footnote.js\|../../../../../ui/webui/resources/preprocessed/cr_components/managed_footnote/managed_footnote.d.ts chrome://resources/cr_components/managed_dialog/managed_dialog.js\|../../../../../ui/webui/resources/preprocessed/cr_components/managed_dialog/managed_dialog.d.ts chrome://resources/\*\|../../../../../ui/webui/resources/preprocessed/\* //resources/\*\|../../../../../ui/webui/resources/preprocessed/\* chrome://resources/polymer/v3_0/\*\|../../../../../../../../third_party/polymer/v3_0/components-chromium/\* //resources/polymer/v3_0/\*\|../../../../../../../../third_party/polymer/v3_0/components-chromium/\* chrome://resources/polymer/v3_0/polymer/polymer_bundled.min.js\|../../../../../../../../third_party/polymer/v3_0/components-chromium/polymer/polymer.d.ts //resources/polymer/v3_0/polymer/polymer_bundled.min.js\|../../../../../../../../third_party/polymer/v3_0/components-chromium/polymer/polymer.d.ts /tools/typescript/definitions/\*\|../../../../../../../../tools/typescript/definitions/\*
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../tools/typescript/ts_library.py", line 220, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "../../tools/typescript/ts_library.py", line 183, in main
    node.RunNode([
  File "/home/boram/work/chromium/src/out/Default/../../third_party/node/node.py", line 34, in RunNode
    raise RuntimeError('Command \'%s\' failed\n%s' % (' '.join(cmd), err))
RuntimeError: Command '/home/boram/work/chromium/src/out/Default/../../third_party/node/linux/node-linux-x64/bin/node /home/boram/work/chromium/src/out/Default/../../third_party/node/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --project gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/tsconfig_build_ts.json' failed
gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/preprocessed/app.ts:16:57 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'chrome://resources/cr_components/help_bubble/help_bubble_mixin.js'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

16 import {HelpBubbleMixin, HelpBubbleMixinInterface} from 'chrome://resources/cr_components/help_bubble/help_bubble_mixin.js';
                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/preprocessed/app.ts:108:12 - error TS4113: This member cannot have an 'override' modifier because it is not declared in the base class 'any'.

108   override connectedCallback() {

gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/preprocessed/app.ts:126:14 - error TS4111: Property 'root' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['root'].

126         this.root!, MARKED_AS_READ_UI_EVENT, this.onMarkedAsRead.bind(this));
                 ~~~~

gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/preprocessed/app.ts:129:12 - error 
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~TS4113: This member cannot have an 'override' modifier because it is not declared in the base class 'any'.

129   override disconnectedCallback() {
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/preprocessed/app.ts:138:10 - error TS4111: Property 'unregisterHelpBubble' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['unregisterHelpBubble'].

138     this.unregisterHelpBubble(READING_LIST_UNREAD_ELEMENT_ID);
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/preprocessed/app.ts:140:47 - error TS4111: Property 'root' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['root'].

140     this.readingListEventTracker_.remove(this.root!, MARKED_AS_READ_UI_EVENT);
                                                  ~~~~

gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/preprocessed/app.ts:143:12 - error TS4113: This member cannot have an 'override' modifier because it is not declared in the base class 'any'.

143   override ready() {
               ~~~~~

gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/preprocessed/app.ts:146:10 - error TS4111: Property 'registerHelpBubble' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['registerHelpBubble'].

146     this.registerHelpBubble(
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/preprocessed/app.ts:152:20 - error TS4111: Property 'root' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['root'].

152               this.root!.querySelector('.unread-item') as HTMLElement | null;
                       ~~~~

gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/preprocessed/app.ts:154:18 - error TS4111: Property 'registerHelpBubble' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['registerHelpBubble'].

154             this.registerHelpBubble(
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/preprocessed/app.ts:265:10 - error TS4111: Property 'notifyHelpBubbleAnchorCustomEvent' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['notifyHelpBubbleAnchorCustomEvent'].

265     this.notifyHelpBubbleAnchorCustomEvent(
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/preprocessed/app.ts:308:49 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof ReadingListAppElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CustomElementConstructor'.
  Type 'ReadingListAppElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 277 more.

308 customElements.define(ReadingListAppElement.is, ReadingListAppElement);
                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../third_party/node/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:4530:101 - error TS2344: Type 'HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]' does not satisfy the constraint 'Element'.
  Type 'HTMLTemplateElement | HTMLElement | HTMLSlotElement | DomModule | HTMLStyleElement | PaperRippleElement | ... 74 more ... | HTMLUListElement' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
    Type 'ReadingListAppElement' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': attributes, classList, className, clientHeight, and 160 more.

4530     getElementsByTagName<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(qualifiedName: K): HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]>;
                                                                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../third_party/node/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:4818:101 - error TS2344: Type 'HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]' does not satisfy the constraint 'Element'.
  Type 'HTMLTemplateElement | HTMLElement | HTMLSlotElement | DomModule | HTMLStyleElement | PaperRippleElement | ... 74 more ... | HTMLUListElement' is not assignable to type 'Element'.

4818     getElementsByTagName<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(qualifiedName: K): HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]>;
                                                                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../third_party/node/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:10170:87 - error TS2344: Type 'HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]' does not satisfy the constraint 'Node'.
  Type 'HTMLTemplateElement | HTMLElement | HTMLSlotElement | DomModule | HTMLStyleElement | PaperRippleElement | ... 74 more ... | HTMLUListElement' is not assignable to type 'Node'.
    Type 'ReadingListAppElement' is missing the following properties from type 'Node': baseURI, childNodes, firstChild, isConnected, and 46 more.

10170     querySelectorAll<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(selectors: K): NodeListOf<HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]>;
                                                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 15 errors in 2 files.

Errors  Files
    12  gen/chrome/browser/resources/side_panel/reading_list/preprocessed/app.ts:16
     3  ../../third_party/node/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:4530
```

I checked the dependency package installation, and checked the gclient sink again.

Comment: Why not checkout a stable tag and try again? Are you trying to build the master/main branch? If yes then it points to nightly and unstable builds which have issues compiling too

Comment: @Asesh Thank you for comment. I succeeded in compiling using tag number 108.
However, while configuring for the build, pdfium third party libary took too long time to clone. After waiting so long, I finally gave up on getting full history.  
like this...


`gclient sync --shallow --no-history`

Does getting pdfium really take this long? I've been waiting for hours

Comment: It will depend on how fast your internet connection is. `gclient sync` when first run usually takes a few minutes even on very fast connection.